# How to run Spring Boot server in background GH Actions?

Tags: spring-boot, github, continuous-integration, github-actions

In my workflow I have defined a step:

```
    - name: Setup Spring Boot App
      run: |
         cd backend/MeetApp
         POSTGRES_USERNAME=postgres POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres nohup ./gradlew bootRun
```

No matter what I try I can't figure out how to start my Spring Boot process, potentially wait for specific time, and then go to the next steps.

Comment: Your indentation is off here, was that just a paste error or is this what your workflow looks like? `run:` should be aligned with `name:`, not with the hyphen.

Comment: Do you have any error messages in the GitHub Actions logs?

Comment: Yes, it was just a paste error. It doesn't throw any errors, the server starts and it's in a constant "task processing" loop, like it waits for this task to finish (which of course shouldn't).

Comment: If gradlew  bootRun does not have a daemon mode (which would launch the process in the background), you can put it in the background yourself with an ampersand (`&`) at the end of the line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

##### TL;DR

Run it in the background with `&`

##### Details

GitHub Actions lets you run a command in the background with the `&` at the end of the line.

For example, this dummy step:

```
  - name: does background work?
    run: |
      echo start && sleep 3 && echo stop &
      echo w1 && sleep 1 && echo w2 && sleep 1 && echo w3 && sleep 1 && echo w4
```

ends up printing, in order: w1, start, w2, w3, stop, w4.

In your case, you would need:

```
  - name: Setup Spring Boot App
    run: |
      cd backend/MeetApp
      POSTGRES_USERNAME=postgres POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres nohup ./gradlew bootRun &
```

And then -- I've tested this -- you can put the command that uses that background process in the same step or in subsequence steps, it'll work either way.

##### Waiting for it

Now, additional details from the comments, you need to wait long enough before starting to use this background process in the next CI steps. A simple `sleep 5` (or choose your time) works, but if you have a dummy query that will succeed only once the background process is booted up, doing it in a loop every second up to a maximum delay will a) wait the shortest time necessary and b) make sure you always wait long enough.

Here's an example that waits at most 20 seconds:

```
  - name: Setup Spring Boot App
    run: |
      cd backend/MeetApp
      POSTGRES_USERNAME=postgres POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres nohup ./gradlew bootRun &
      for attempt in {1..20}; do sleep 1; if <test-command>; then echo ready; break; fi; echo waiting...; done
```

That `<test-command>` should exit 0 if gradlew has booted, non-zero otherwise. With this loop, CI will not move on to the next step until the boot is complete.

Comment: I tried adding & at the end of the line but judging by logs presented by Github Actions, it doesn't boot the server. The last line logged in this task is "Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)" and then it switches to next steps. I'm not sure though if it runs and boots in the background but just doesn't log.

Comment: Right, what happens is that the process continues in the background, but the console logs are detached. You'll need to save the logs to a file if you want to see them.

Comment: Oh my, I increased the sleep time in following step and it works! Just had to wait a bit longer :). Thank you for help anyway!

Comment: It seems the following steps relying on the server were just to quick to run and I had to wait a little longer for the server to boot up.

Comment: Right, that's always a challenge when you need to boot up a server in one step and then use it. A "nice" server will provide a "ping" mechanism you could use to detect readyness, but a simple sleep works too.

Comment: Actually, the ping you could use is to run a dummy query every second until it succeeds, that way you could minimize how long you wait and at the same time be robust: the time it takes longer to boot, for some reason, you'll wait long enough that time too.