# How to set up GitHub Actions to execute e2e tests on source code in a different repository

Tags: github-actions

I want to set up a GitHub Action to run E2E test every time there is a new commit to my application repo, but this E2E test is located in **a different repo**. So I structured the YAML file as follows:

```
 steps:

  - name: Checkout source code under test
    uses: actions/checkout@v2

  - name: Start local server
    run: npm install && npm start #In order to run E2E test, test server/ app must be started
  
  - name: Checkout E2E test from a separate repo
    uses: actions/checkout@v2
    with:
      repository: <my_username>/<my_e2e_test_repo> 
      path: cypress-tests    # Where to checkout the code

  - name: Install dependencies for e2e test
    run: cd cypress-tests && npm install 
  
  - name: Run tests
    run: cd cypress-tests && npx cypress run
```

The server (application under test) seems to have started fine, according to the log:

```
Compiled successfully!
You can now view the client in the browser.
  Local:            http://localhost:3000
  On Your Network:  http://10.1.0.15:3000/
```

However, the workflow hung there and could not reach the next steps (*Checkout E2E test*)

[image]

(*On our own machine, we would need to open another Command Prompt to execute the next commands. So, I suppose we need to do the same in Workflow. But how?*)

Can anyone show me where I did it wrong? or it is not an appropriate way to do it?

Comment: _"the workflow hung there and could not reach the next steps"_ - that step doesn't finish until the command exits (and doesn't proceed to the next step unless it exits 0, by default).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run Spring Boot server in background GH Actions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74245389/how-to-run-spring-boot-server-in-background-gh-actions)

Comment: @jonrsharpe I see, any suggestions on how to run the next steps without exiting that command? as we need to keep in running in order to run e2e test

Comment: Adding an ampersand (&) at the end of the command will make it run in the background and process the next step immediately. However, by the time cypress run, it couldn't find a running server and failed: 
"Cypress failed to verify that your server is running. Please start this server and then run Cypress again."

Comment: Then get the server to start faster or Cypress to wait longer, but that's solved your initial problem.

Comment: Or build your server in a docker container in a job, then publish that to github container registry and then run the tests with the container running as a sidecart/service container in the next job.

Comment: @jessehouwing Thank you, that's the best option, it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the best option here is to [publish your application under test as a docker container (to GitHub packages' container registry)](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-container-registry#authenticating-in-a-github-actions-workflow) and the [use that container as a service container in the e2e test job](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-containerized-services/about-service-containers).

That way GitHub actions will automatically take care of the lifecycle of your webapp for the duration of the e2e test job:

```yaml
name: e2e container example
on: push

jobs:
  e2e:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    # Service containers to run with `e2e-job`
    services:
      # Label used to access the service container
      webapp:
        # ghcr image
        image: ghcr.io/<YOUR_USER_OR_ORG>/<IMAGE_NAME>:<IMAGE_TAG>
        ports:
          - 8080:8080
```